# Multi-dimensional array or json object from nested list item in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I've a nested list items. I want to make an multi-dimensional array or json object from the list items. I've tried something like below. But I'm not getting the expected output.

> The depth of the list item can be more. So, I'll define a recursive method to do this later.

[DEMO Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shawon922/Lu85g8rL/27/)

HTML:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
    <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
            <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 1</div>
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">                    
                    <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 2</div>
                    <ol class="dd-list">
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">

                            <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 3</div>
                            <ol class="dd-list">
                                <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">

                                    <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 4</div>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">

                            <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 3</div>
                            <ol class="dd-list">
                                <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">

                                    <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 4</div>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var subIndicTreeObj = {};
var tempObj = [];
var parentId = 0;
var parentId1 = 0;
var parentId2 = 0;

$('#nestable > ol > li').each(function(index, value) { 
    parentId = 0;
    parentId1 = 0;
    parentId2 = 0;

    tempObj.push({'sub_indic_id': $(this).attr('data-id'), 'parent_id': parentId});


    if ($(this).has('ol').length > 0) { 

        parentId = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $(this).find('ol > li').each(function(index1, value1) { 

            tempObj.push({'sub_indic_id': $(this).attr('data-id'), 'parent_id': parentId});


            if ($(this).has('ol').length > 0) {  

                parentId1 = $(this).attr('data-id');

                $(this).find('ol > li').each(function(index2, value2) { 

                    tempObj.push({'sub_indic_id': $(this).attr('data-id'), 'parent_id': parentId1});

                    if ($(this).has('ol').length > 0) { 


                        parentId2 = $(this).attr('data-id');

                        $(this).find('ol > li').each(function(index3, value3) { 

                            tempObj.push({'sub_indic_id': $(this).attr('data-id'), 'parent_id': parentId2});

                        });
                    }

                });
            } 
        });
    } 
});

subIndicTreeObj = tempObj;

console.log(subIndicTreeObj);
```

Current Output:

```
 [
  Object{
    sub_indic_id="1",
    parent_id=0
  },
  Object{
    sub_indic_id="2",
    parent_id="1"
  },
  Object{
    sub_indic_id="3",
    parent_id="2"
  },
  Object{
    sub_indic_id="4",
    parent_id="3"
  },
  Object{
    sub_indic_id="4",
    parent_id="2"
  },
  Object{
    sub_indic_id="3",
    parent_id="1"
  },
  Object{
    sub_indic_id="4",
    parent_id="3"
  },
  Object{
    sub_indic_id="4",
    parent_id="1"
  },
  Object{
    sub_indic_id="3",
    parent_id="1"
  },
  Object{
    sub_indic_id="4",
    parent_id="3"
  },
  Object{
    sub_indic_id="4",
    parent_id="1"
  }
]
```

I want the immediate parent_id of a child. But I'm getting the top level parent_id for some list item. Such as,

```
Object{
    sub_indic_id="4",
    parent_id="1"
  }
```

Can anybody help to find out the problem ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand if it's the expected behaviour, anyway, it's recursive, and also find the first child. I just added a `>` before the `ol > li` selector.

Note that i also added a `data-id='0'` to `id="nestable"` to get the first parent id.

**edit**

For more detail about `>` selector as asked in comment, i suggest to have look to some documentation. I mostly learned from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp).
Reporting from that link

> The element>element selector is used to select elements with a specific parent.

So, in your code with `ol > li` you were retriving **all** the `li` children of every `ol`, contained in `$(this)`.

With `> ol > li` you retrive the direct children of the object on which you're searching, and not also the children of chidren.

```js
var subIndicTreeObj = [];

function findLiChild($obj, parentId) {
  $obj.find('> ol > li').each(function(index1, value1) {
    subIndicTreeObj.push({
      'sub_indic_id': $(this).attr('data-id'),
      'parent_id': parentId
    });

    findOlChild($(this));
  });
}

function findOlChild($obj) {
  if ($obj.has('ol').length > 0) {
    findLiChild($obj, $obj.attr('data-id'));
  }
}

findOlChild($('#nestable'));

console.log(subIndicTreeObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dd" id="nestable" data-id="0">
  <ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
      <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 1</div>
      <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
          <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 2</div>
          <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">

              <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 3</div>
              <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">

                  <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 4</div>
                </li>
              </ol>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">

          <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 3</div>
          <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">

              <div class="dd-handle">Sub-indicator 4</div>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But can you tell me what's the purpose of the `>` before `ol > li` ?

Comment: Sure. It retrive only the first level children of the object on which you call `find`. I try to add a better explanation in my answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple loop:

```
var data = [];//create the array
$('.dd-item').each(function() {//loop each item
  var parent = $(this).parent().closest('.dd-item');//get the parent
  var parent_id = 0;//set 0 if it has no parent
  if (parent.length) {
    parent_id = parent.attr('data-id');//set parent id if it has
  }
  data.push({
    parent_id: parent_id ,sub_indic_id: $(this).attr('data-id')
  });//append to the array
});
console.log(data);
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/uwqqmz86/

Comment: OP is looking to do the reverse

Comment: @Rajesh you mean the child is note and the parent id the leaf?\

Comment: No. I mean he has the markup and he wishes to generate JSON, Please check other answer